# I/O performance in Node.js worker threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker, worker-thread

Here's an example with worker thread that takes ~600ms on local machine for synchronous I/O:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { isMainThread, Worker, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

const filename = './foo.txt';

if (isMainThread) {
    (async () => {
        console.time('!');

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const worker = new Worker(__filename, { workerData: filename });

            worker.on('message', resolve);
            worker.on('error', reject);
            worker.on('exit', (code) => {
                if (code !== 0)
                    reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
            });
        });

        console.timeEnd('!');   
    })().catch(console.error);
} else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        fs.readFileSync(workerData);

    parentPort.postMessage('ok');
}
```

The same example with single thread takes ~2s for asynchronous I/O:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = './foo.txt';

console.time('worker');

(function read(i) {
    if (i < 100) {
        fs.readFile(filename, () => read(++i));
        return;
    }

    console.timeEnd('worker');  
})(0);
```

Obviously, synchronous blocking operation is more efficient here.

Node.js [worker thread reference](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) states:

> Workers are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations; do not use them for I/O, since Node.js’s built-in mechanisms for performing operations asynchronously already treat it more efficiently than Worker threads can.

What are the grounds for this statement?

What is the difference between main and worker threads regarding I/O?

Isn't the purpose of a worker to not be limited to non-blocking asynchronous operations?

What are the circumstances under which I/O performance may be less efficient in worker threads?

Comment: *sigh* this question has been asked so many times in so many different forms. asynchronous IO != synchronous IO on another thread. only File IO and DNS lookup are done in the libuv built-in threadpool and you shouldn't mess with writing your own IO mechanism.

Comment: I see what you mean with *asynchronous IO != synchronous IO on another thread* but the question is specific to worker threads. Why would there be such statement while it seems to be misleading for a developer? If the reference compares async I/O in main thread vs async I/O in a worker ( the comparison seems to be apples vs apples but it's hardly fair because a worker doesn't need to be non-blocking), then some explanation is welcome.

Comment: If you agree to the statement **asynchronous IO != synchronous IO on another thread**, than what is the question? enqueuing an io task to another thread doesn't make it non-blocking.

Comment: The question is what is the point of this statement and what are circumstances under which it may be more efficient to do I/O in main rather than in worker thread, like the reference suggests.

Comment: May be less percentage of cpu is allocated for asynchronous thread, while the load is the same.. And main thread gets a head start.. One bear against 1 wolf, who’s going to win.. But one bear against a whole pack is another story..

Comment: Again, where is the contradiction? the manual says don't use worker threads as an IO workers and you example makes this claim stronger. under no case you should use a threadpool as a way to parallelize your IO tasks

Comment: Is that your real code? It should throw “TypeError: Not enough arguments to MessagePort.postMessage”. Also, how big is foo.txt?

Comment: Threads are useful for CPU intensive processes becuase the overhead of creating a thread is made up for by the efficient use of the CPU. I/O bound processes are more efficient on the main thread because the overhead of creating the additional thread is negated by the IO call blocking that thread, i.e. `Node.js’s built-in mechanisms for performing operations asynchronously ..(is already)... more efficient` so the overhead of creating the thread is a waste

Comment: @DavidHaim How does it make the claim stronger? It takes less time in a worker. I wouldn't use blocking op in main thread but in a worker it doesn't seem to be a problem. The example is there to prove the point that *do not use them for I/O* statement is wrong. If you suggest that it may be different for other I/O ops then please, consider answering the question; I believe it's applicable to wide audience.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks, fixed it. It's big enough, several Mbs.

Comment: Even though main thread is more efficient people will most likely use a separate thread for IO because of possible hang up due to slow bandwidth or locks..

Comment: `readFile` is probably doing something wrong or assuming you’ll use it on smaller files. With a 40 MB foo.txt, I get 10 seconds for `fs.readFile`, 2.3 seconds for `fs.readFileSync` in a worker, 4.5 seconds for a manual equivalent to `fs.readFile` using `fs.open` + `fs.read`, and 3.0 seconds when tweaking its buffer size. (`fs.createReadStream` is comparable.)

Comment: "asynchronous IO != synchronous IO on another thread" should only be valid when using non sync fs methods right? Else if i use sync methods then its using the same thread for waiting rather than libuv thread pool, i agree it compute inefficient ...

Answer (score 1):

You have found an obvious performance problem in Node.js.

I guess that you are testing it on very large files, as this is what this problem affects the most.

The problem is that `readFileSync` reads the whole file in one operation (one `read` syscall), while `readFile` reads in chunks of 512Kb.

I have submitted a PR to fix this, here is the discussion:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41436

With this PR `readFile` becomes slightly faster then `readFileSync` **without** the overhead of creating a new thread. If you add the new thread creation, the difference is even more pronounced.

Node.js is made for asynchronous IO and this is what works best.