# Node.js performance in file system I/O across multiple disk drives: worker threads or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, io, node-worker-threads

I've read several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52648229/1193251) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61421666) here about the performance benefits of Node.js' ability to performantly handle file I/O operations quickly in a non-blocking way versus using worker threads with either blocking or non-blocking requests, however none seem to answer the question I have.

I'm writing a Node.js application that will be opening, hashing, and writing very large files (multiple gigs) that are stored on multiple hard drives. I'm exploring the idea of worker threads, as they'd allow me to isolate commands to a particular hard drive. For example: assume I have a thread handling copying one file on hard drive A to hard drive B, and another thread handling copying one file from hard drive C to hard drive D.

Assuming I scale this to many more hard drives all at the same time, does it make more sense for me to just use Node.js without worker threads and let it handle all these requests, or does worker threads make more sense if I can isolate I/O by drive, and handle multiple drives' worth of requests at the same time?

Given what I've read, worker threads seem like the obvious solution, but I've also seen that just letting the single Node.js process handle a queue of file I/O is generally faster. Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about where the IO is scheduled from, that's carried out in an underlying [libuv thread pool](https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html#threadpool) which is shared for a single node.js os process. Worker threads won't provide any more IO isolation than a job queue would.  The thread pool size will need to be increased if you want to manage more than one copy per process.

Comment: What hashing are you doing? That's likely to be cpu intensive so you need to be careful where/how that runs.  At first glance I would run a node.js process per drive group and distribute work for the group with some pub/sub mechanism like zeromq. I assume it's spinning disk to be this careful?

Comment: @Matt: Great question! I'll be needing to mirror file contents, so my plan was to (if I need to duplicate the file) `createReadStream` through a file, and while doing that, run it through some function in the `crypto` library, while also `createWriteStream`ing to the destination file. I think this at least allows me to hash it while writing it (two birds; one stone). I'm also planning on running `node-exiftool` and using node's `fs` module's `stat` functions to fetch file properties/metadata so I know I only have to double check the hash if some of the metadata has changed (much faster).

Comment: @Matt, My general assumption is that at some point with so much going on, I'll eventually hit my CPU limit, which for this server, I don't mind if it's sitting there just processing away. Namely, my goal is I want to utilize the most out of my system as I can. I expect if a bunch of file transfers are happening, I'll hit I/O limits before I hit CPU limits, since file hashes are much less likely to be occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Apparently (based on a comment below), nodejs has only one thread pool shared across all the worker threads.  If that's the case, then the only way to get a separate pool per disk would be to use multiple processes, not multiple threads.

Or, you could enlarge the worker pool and then make your own queuing system that only puts a couple requests for each separate disk into the worker pool at a time, giving you more parallelism across separate drives.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

(some of which still applies)

Without worker threads, you will have a single libuv thread pool serving all disk I/O requests.  So, they will all go into the same pool and once the threads in that pool are busy (regardless of what disk they are serving), new requests will be queued in the order they arrive.  This is potentially less than ideal because if you have 5 requests for drive A and 1 request for drive B and 1 request for drive C, you would like to not just fill up the pool with 5 requests for drive A first because that will make the requests for drive B and drive C wait until several requests on drive A are done before they can get started.  This loses some opportunities for some parallelism across the separate drives.  Of course, whether you truly get parallelism on separate drives also depends upon the drive controller implementation and whether they actually have separate SATA controllers or not.

If you did use worker threads, one nodejs worker thread for each disk, you can at least guarantee that you have a separate pool of OS threads in the thread pool for each disk and you can make it much more likely that no set of requests for one drive will keep the requests for the other drives from getting a chance to start and miss their opportunity to run in parallel with requests to other drives.

Now, of course, all of this discussion is theoretical.  In the world of disk drives, controller cards, operating systems on top of the controllers with libuv on top of that with nodejs on top of that, there are lots of opportunities for the theoretical discussion to not bear out in real world measurements.

So, the only way to really know for sure would be to implement the worker thread option and then benchmark compare it to a non-worker thread option with several different disk usage scenarios, including a couple you think might be worst case.  So, as with any important performance-related question, you will inevitably have to benchmark and measure to know for sure one way or the other.  And, your results will need very careful construction of the benchmark tests too in order to be maximally useful.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I was thinking that it'd be a certainty that I'd run into some max I/O limit, which I'm fine with. One of the things I was concerned about was in the cases where I'll be reading and hashing a file's contents at the same time and if I have several worker threads doing that at the same time, would the separate worker threads be competing for CPU on the single process? I was looking at clusters which create different processes on different processor cores, and I'm wondering if you think that might be a better option or does `libuv` create separate processes?

Comment: @kyle - If your processing has any CPU intensive stuff, then using multiple threads can make a significant difference.  It isn't clear to me whether just calculating a file hash is actually CPU-intensive enough to matter.  You would have to be pegging or near pegging a single CPU nearly much of the time for you to get benefit from involving more CPUs as the code would most typically be I/O bound anyway.  Again, this is something you'd have to test and measure.

Comment: @kyle - The worker threads are true OS-level threads so they should get full access to all CPU cores even if they are all in the same process.  I don't see any particular reason to use clustering vs. threading here unless you want the resiliency of multiple processes (at the cost of a little more memory overhead).

Comment: @kyle - Threading gives you an option to use shared memory between the threads (with appropriate concurrency protections) if that's useful.  In a performance sensitive and CPU-bound app I was working on, I found it very useful to be able to use shared memory to pass large pieces of data efficiently to threads that would have been far less efficient if I was using clustering.  But, it really depends upon your app.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help! Yeah, I wasn't clear on processes and threads. How CPUs work is quite a bit outside my usual expertise of software engineering. It sounds like threads would likely offer me more performance, and this gives me an opportunity to learn threads for the first time. That said, I'll do some performance testing to be sure - the code will be reusable regardless. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @jfriend00 The node io thread pool is initialised once per process and shared between the event loops. A worker thread won't segregate fileio/dns/queue_work - https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html

Comment: @kyle - Apparently, you don't get a separate thread pool for each thread so that changes the possibilities.  I edited the answer some to mention that.

Comment: @matt and jfriend00, thanks for the teamwork there. That does change some of the possibilities. Still a bit torn, but you both have given me lots to consider. It's probably best to do some benchmarking!

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the per process model, it looks the same as the worker threads suggested by jfriend00 just the IPC mechanism changes.

Manage the job queue from a "head" manager process and split the drive/hashing work into a node process for each worker so there's no IO/CPU contention in each worker.

Have each worker pick up a single job at a time from a work queue for it's drive (or drive group).  All you need is reliability, monitoring for workers that aren't processing and a return channel for worker completion/errors.

The queuing mechanism doesn't really matter, a database table would suffice (or any type of network messaging http, grpc, nanomsg, redis, nats, rabbitmq). This is based on not needing to share a lot of data between the manager and the workers other than a simple job messages "Hey worker, here is a file go process it", "I am done with this file" or "I broke, help!"

```
| Manager                        |
| Pub 1 2 3                      |
```

```
| Sub 1    | Sub 2    | Sub 3    |
| Worker   | Worker   | Worker   |
|          |          |          |
| DriveA   | DriveC   | DriveE   |
| DriveB   | DriveD   | DriveF   |
```

Run a worker per core if the process ends up CPU bound, or as few as you need to manage the IO requirements. Workers can easily expand as you add drives or more servers.